# Where is the right place to report a defect in the Saxon XSLT processor?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've google around but every forum I found, which might suit for this purpose is closed or broken. Where is the right place to report a defect in the Saxon XSLT processor?

For the curious, here is my little gem that crashes Saxon, and will be the subject of my report.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <t/>
  <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="
   'Two false values'[for $i in 1 to 2 return false()]"/>
  </xsl:message>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been an official site for bug reporting at dev.saxonica.com for a few months now, which you are welcome to use; but you're welcome to use the saxon-help list at SourceForge as well (we don't positively encourage users of the commercial product to use that resource, as it's provided for the benefit of the open source community, but if people do, they will get an answer).

I look forward to seeing the bug report. Make sure to supply enough information to reproduce the problem, including product version numbers and of course the error messages or stack trace.

Note that the current version is 9.4.0.4. When problems occur in an earlier version but not in the latest branch, we usually won't fix them unless the fix is important to a paying customer.

Comment: The bug has now been reproduced and is logged here: https://dev.saxonica.com/community/issues/1589

Answer (score 2):

The Saxon mailing list https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/saxon-help should work, it is active. I am not sure however that is the preferred way these days, but I am sure Michael Kay can tell you later.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [saxon-help](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/saxon-help) mailing list. It's not a bug by the way, Saxon gives you a clear error message:

> FORG0006: Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two
>   or more items starting with a boolean

If you change `1 to 2` to `1 to 1` it works.

Comment: That's not what I get. The application crashes. I might be on a different version to you.

Comment: Before filing a bug make sure you are on the latest version of Saxon.  There's no point sending someone on a wild goose chase if the problem has already been fixed.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin - I get the validation error `[Saxon-HE 9.4.0.3] Internal error: invalid slot number for local variable (No slot allocated)` when opening your XSLT in oXygen. (For all 3 (HE/PE/EE) versions of 9.4.)